# Convert Markdown links to HTML with Pandoc

Tags: html, hyperlink, markdown, pandoc

In my new project I have multiple Markdown files which are linked to each other. These links refer to the original `.md` files.

**Example:**

File *README.md*

```
...
1. [Development documentation](Development.md)
1. [User documentation](Usage.md)
...
```

If I convert these files with Pandoc, e.g., to HTML files, all links are still pointing to the original `.md` file. I'm looking for a way to also convert the link type, which means that output files should refer to the output file type such as HTML, PDF, [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX), etc. Is there a way to convert the internal link type with Pandoc?

I use this to convert the files:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t html5 input.md -o output.html
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a filter that checks every [link](http://scorreia.com/software/panflute/code.html#panflute.elements.Link) element and—if the URL ends with `.md`—replaces it with `.html`.

Example with Python, using the [panflute](http://scorreia.com/software/panflute/) package:

```
import panflute as pf

def action(elem, doc):
    if isinstance(elem, pf.Link) and elem.url.endswith('.md'):
        elem.url = elem.url[:-3] + '.html'
        return elem

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pf.run_filter(action)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great! I am just wondering if there's no simple way by using Pandoc options?

Comment: @P.Tail no, there is no out-of-the-box way to do that. Markdown assumes that your links already point to the rendered HTML documents and does not alter your URLs. In fact, any altering of URLs would be a bug. Of course, using a custom-built plugin (like the one here) is possible with various Markdown parsers. But it has to be custom because only you know your specific needs and no single solution could possibly meet the needs of most (let alone all) users.

Answer (score 39):

Example with the [built-in Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html):

```
-- links-to-html.lua
function Link(el)
  el.target = string.gsub(el.target, "%.md", ".html")
  return el
end
```

Then:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t html5 input.md -o output.html --lua-filter=links-to-html.lua
```

Comment: Note that # is not a valid Lua comment. Use -- if you want to keep the first line.

Comment: I would expect this to preserver links and only change the href;
but the given command also converts the  "a" tags into "embed" tags, which is somehow worse? I wonder what I could be doing wroing?

Answer (score 3):

A slight modification to [Sergio Correia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41005658/) also catches anchor links in documents. Take care; in some rare cases this might garble links...

```
import panflute as pf

def action(elem, doc):
    if isinstance(elem, pf.Link):
        if elem.url.endswith('.md'):
            elem.url = elem.url[:-3] + '.html'
            return elem
        elif elem.url.find('.md#'):
            elem.url = elem.url.replace('.md#', '.html#')
            return elem

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pf.run_filter(action)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are going to serve you HTML pages via a web server, it is relatively simple to resolve all `*.md` URLs as `*.html` ones instead of rewriting them via Pandoc, e.g., using [NGinx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx):

```
location ~ \.md$ {
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.*)\.md$ $1 permanent;
  }
}

location / {
  try_files /$uri /$uri.html;
}
```

Alternatively, you can replace all `md` links with `html` using `sed`
(taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/jose8a/8dce609b8dd9429a194e)):

> Change all internal file URLs from pointing to *.md links and instead point to the local *.html file
>
> 1. recursively run this sed command (programmatically replace FILENAME)
>
>    ```
>    sed -n -i.bak '/href="\./s/\.md/\.html/' FILENAME.html
>    ```
> 2. alternatively, run the following command instead (programmatically replace FILENAME)
>
>    ```
>    sed -e '/href="\./s/\.md/\.html/' FILENAME.html > FILENAME.html.tmp && mv FILENAME.html.tmp FILENAME.html`
>    ```

Comment: I would not recommend this approach, because there could be link in code sections which you would not want to convert, and similar other complications you might not think of at the moment, and which you automatically circumvent if you use an other tool for parsing, like pandoc.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, so I made *[md_htmldoc](https://github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/md_htmldoc)*.

It finds all of the `.md` files in a directory and then makes a separate directory where all the Markdown files has been converted to HTML.

It fixes hyperlinks (thanks to [Sergio Correia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993488/convert-markdown-links-to-html-with-pandoc/41005658#41005658)).

It also gathers up any local file references so that links to images and such still work.

Comment: I saw in your code (`get_references.py`), that you use regex to find links in markdown. I would not recommend this approach, because there might be links in code sections which you would not want to convert, and similar other complications you might not think of at the moment. you could automatically circumvent this, if you always use an other tool for parsing, like _pandoc_ (as you also do per _panflute_).

Comment: @hoijui: ``get_references.py`` isn't used to convert something - it's just used to find references. Every found reference gets checked if it refers to a local file - if yes, then it gets added to ``doc_relevant``, which then is used to (1) either compile a markdown to html or (2) copy that file to ``HTML_DIR``

Comment: ok, thanks :-)
still, you might miss references this way, for the reasons mentioned above. Only building an AST can do it properly (which is what pandoc does, for example). using filters and AST(raw?) output with pandoc, it is quite easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using a Makefile to drive conversion, here is a Makefile fragment that provides a rule transforming a .md into a .html with link adjusted:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

%.html: %.md
    ( set -eu -o pipefail ; \
    pandoc -i $< -t html | \
    sed -E 's/<a href="([^"]*).md/<a href="\1.html/g' > $@.tmp && mv -vf $@.tmp $@ ; )
```

If `test.md` exists in current directory, `make test.html` will do it.

The rule also takes care of not clobbering an existing HTML file (whatever the reason) until the conversion actually succeeds.

Comment: Notice that the rule does not try to be smart in case of twisted links, like `[foo](bar.md.somethingelse)`.

Comment: Elegant, simple and very effective. `sed` is almost magical for all it can do for you!